# Can't start laravel-echo-server using Supervisor

Tags: laravel, centos7, supervisord, laravel-echo

If I manually run laravel-echo-server - it works fine. But I can't run laravel-echo-server using supervisor: i'm getting error on frontend

```
GET http://example.com:6001/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MO25vx0net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

echoserver.log has been created but always empty

I've tried to restart and update supervisor, using sudo

/etc/supervisord.conf:

```
 [program:echo-server]
    command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start
    dierctory=/var/www/www-root/data/www/example.com
    autostart=true
    user=root
    autorestart=true
    stdout_logfile=/var/www/www-root/data/www/example.com/storage/logs/echoserver.log
```

laravel-echo-server.json:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "fe0ee01ccace98c",
            "key": "1138421388769fdbbf88293eb329c16a"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem solved by replacing this

```
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start
```

to this

```
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/www-root/data/www/example.com
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your configuration for `directory`.

```
dierctory=/var/www/www-root/data/www/example.com
 ^^^

# It should be:
directory=/var/www/www-root/data/www/example.com`
```